# Import bootstrap.scss with @use and/or @forward instead of @import

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, node-sass

Is there a way to import the bootstrap.scss to my own sass file using @use and/or @forward without using @import?

Comment: Did you try it? What didn't work?

Comment: I did some more digging around the net, and it seems to work. But by default bootstrap do not support use and forward, because their own scss files uses import. So to use use and forward, I need to change the bootstrap scss to use use and forward, instead of import. Which can be tedious and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to touch the bootstrap files for when you wanna update in the future and whatnot.

Not sure if this is correct, but this is the conclusion i came to right now. So i will have to use import for my school project.